# Translation of "She is too talkative for my liking"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-usage

If I want to say that I don't like someone because she talks too much, how should I say it?

> Sie redet zu viel nach meinem Geschmack?

Basically I am looking for the right words for "to my liking".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just put it at the beginning of your sentence:

> Nach meinem Geschmack redet sie zu viel!

Comment: Some little variation:    "Für meinen Geschmack..."  is also common

Answer (score 2):

You could even go shorter than in the other answer and use the Dative.

> Sie redet mir zu viel.

You can often use the simple Dative to say *for someone’s liking,* which at least to me is pretty close to *for me*.

Comment: In der Kürze liegt die Würze. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Oder auch (ohne das so "langweilige" `viel`):

> Sie ist mir zu gesprächig.

Ein bißchen "böser", abwertend:

> Sie ist mir zu geschwätzig.

Comment: @Em1: Danke für die Korrektur. Das erste `sz` unter meinem Namen seid 18 Jahren. Na schön, hab ja auch 'ne Fehler gemacht.  Hättest Du ein `ss` auch korrigiert?

Comment: *bisschen* ist ok.